# Probability in two dimensions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a two dimensional coordinate system.

A bug is located at point (0,0). Every Minute it is moving either exactly one point up or exactly one point to the right with equal probability.

**What is the probability for the bug to be at point (7,5) after 12 Minutes?**

**My thoughts:**

This situation can be modeled with a coin tossed 12 times. The outcomes are heads (h) or tails (t).

So we have $\Omega=\{(r_1,...,r_{12})\ |\ r_i\in\{h,t\}\ \forall\ i\in\{1,...,12\}\}$

with $p(\omega)=\frac{1}{2^{12}}$

---

Here's where I'm stuck though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ,,, so you want the probability of exactly $7$ heads in $12$ tosses. Do you know how to count the number of ways to choose the $7$ positions for the heads?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Is defining a random Variable X: $\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ the right idea? Given $X$ is the number of heads in 12 tosses?

Comment: You are working too hard with complicated vocabulary. You do not need "random variables" and your $\Omega$. Can you answer the question for five tosses ending at $(2,3)$ by writing out all the possible sequences? @Arthur has hinted at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Any specific sequence of coin tosses has probability $\frac{1}{2^{12}}$ of happening. How many different sequences lets you end up at the point $(7, 5)$?

Comment: I believe any sequence that has exactly heads? But how many of such sequences are there?

Comment: @de_dust I really have no idea how to give a short hint that doesn't give it all away, but... You have a sequence of 12 coin tosses available, and you want to... _choose_... seven of them to be heads. How many different ways can you do that?

Comment: 12 nCr 7 different ways?

Comment: @de_dust Exactly. Usually, one considers 12 to _be_ the n and 7 is the r, so it's 12 C 7. Or $\binom{12}7$ if you want to be fancy. But that is not of great importance.